# Зачем это нужно в Maven?

Tags: maven

```
<product-artifactId>${pro}-root</product-artifactId>
        <app.configuration-path>${basedir}/config</app.configuration-path>

<module>tu/projects/${pro}/${pro}-web</module>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за директивы после знака доллара? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Подстановка значений из блока properties

Comment: @etki Большое пребольшое спасибо!